# Finished Present Perfect Continuous

Tags: present-perfect

Can I say "I have been living there since 2001 but I don't live there now."?

Comment: No; 'I have been living there since ...' demands you still be there. 'I was living there from 2001 (to 2012), but I don't live there now.'

Comment: Or "I had been living there" (past perfect).

Comment: Note: "I had been living there *until* 2001" means you moved out of there in 2001. "I had been living there *since* 2001" means you moved in there in 2001.

Comment: You would simply say that you lived there from 2001 to 2009. No continuous at all.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lived; have lived; have been living](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167499/lived-have-lived-have-been-living)

Answer (score 1):

The first clause contradicts the second. The first implies that I am still living there. The second explicitly contradicts the first.  So there is no *grammar* error, but there is an inconsistency.  You need to use a past tense to express a past state.:

> I was living there from 2001 to 2012...
>
> I had been living there since 2001 ...
>
> I lived there between 2001 and 2012...